# О практике передачи ответственности за TLS соединение между процессами?

Tags: c, winapi, https, tls, cryptoapi

Добрый день.

Меня интересует вопрос передачи ответственности за TLS соединение между процессами. Я хочу установить TLS соединение и провести первичный обмен сообщениями в одном процессе, а потом передать соединение дочернему процессу, чтоб он дальше работал с ним самостоятельно.

Собственно застрял я с тем как передавать мандаты клиента и сервера от родительского к дочернему процессу.

Как это сделать? Можно ли вообще как-то передать SecHandle в другой процесс как массив байт или еще как-то?

Родитель не может олицетворить себя клиентом, используя его мандат безопасности (это я уже проверял).